# Regarding Amazon ec2 cluster compute instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a question regarding ec2 cluster. Can anyone tell me that how many instances are exactly in a cluster of ec2? Let me explain what I meant by this question. I want to benchmark an application by running it on an instance and the bench marker will run on different instances. I will create a Virtual private network between the instances so that when a bench marker will send packets to the application, it will respond to the packets and the bench marker will count the number of responses (this is how the application and the bench marker works). This can be done on multiple instances (I haven't tried it yet, but I believe so). How exactly this can be done on a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Cluster compute instances are a type of instances, they are names like large, xlarge, etc.  So it just contains one virtual machine and you can add as many of these as you need(and can afford).

Here are the specs of the cluster compute instances:

Cluster Compute Quadruple Extra Large 23 GB memory, 33.5 EC2 Compute Units, 1690 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform, 10 Gigabit Ethernet

Cluster Compute Eight Extra Large 60.5 GB memory, 88 EC2 Compute Units, 3370 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform, 10 Gigabit Ethernet

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: Thanks much. I have a one confusion in my mind that if I add instances in a cluster then do I have to create a virtual private network of those instances so that they can communicate with each other ? (like in  the case of individual instances) or it is done automatically as they become a part of the cluster?

Comment: Not automatically part of the cluster nor do you need to create your own vpn.  Basically when you launch an instance(under the details of the instance tab) there is a internal IP..usually starts with 10... You can point your other servers to use that internal IP to communicate quickly.  There is an external ip(which you connect with) but its slower to go outside and then back in the network everytime.  Also using the IP saves you money because you won't get charged for any traffic between instances.